# how to simplify the code to create an array of objects?

Tags: php

i want to create an array of objects. this is the code but i want to simplify the code.

```
$cols1 = new stdClass;
$cols1->id = '';
$cols1->label = 'COMPANY';
$cols1->pattern = '';
$cols1->type = "string";

$cols2 = new stdClass;
$cols2->id = '';
$cols2->label = 'TOTAL';
$cols2->pattern = '';
$cols2->type = "number";
```

Comment: How do you get the data, if you have to write them manually in code you could use a simple function to map the arguments to an object or better yet use a custom class and a proper constructor for that!?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What are your inputs and outputs?  Are there exactly two elements? What would you then do with the resulting objects? See [ask].

Comment: Furthermore, the code you have posted does not actually create an array, so it looks like you are asking for code to be written, rather than a review of existing working code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast an associative array into object. Therefore just create a list of arrays and add an object casting operator before each array definition:

```
$cols = [
    (object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'LABEL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'string'],
    (object) ['id' => '', 'label' => 'TOTAL', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'number'],
];
```

as simple as that